# How do I get the value of URL from PUT request? In Ruby

Tags: ruby, api, httparty

What I need is the value of URL from the PUT request.
Here is the result of the PUT request.
Response: `{"result":{"attempts":1,"url":null}}`

I can't tell where is the problem.

```rb
loop do
  response = HTTParty.put("#{API_ENDPOINT}/challenges", headers: { 'X-Challenge-Id' => challenge_id })
  puts "Response: #{response}"

  if response['error']
    puts "Error: #{response['error']}"
  elsif response.key?('result')
    result = response['result']
    attempts = result['attempts']
    url = result['url']
    if attempts.zero?
      puts "Challenge failed. Attempts: #{attempts}"
    elsif url.nil?
      puts "Challenge succeeded but no URL available. Attempts: #{attempts}"
    else
      puts "Challenge succeeded. Attempts: #{attempts}"
      puts "URL with keyword: #{API_ENDPOINT}#{url}"
    end

    break
  end
end
```

The thing I want to do,
Start a challenge by making a POST HTTP request to/challenges.
At the scheduled invocation time (actives_at) time in the response, an HTTP request is sent as PUT to/challenges. At this time, it is necessary to give the challenge ID (id) to the X-Challenge-Id header.

I tried to print out the error message but seems the challenge succeeded just no URL available.

Comment: Are you asking why `url` is `null` in the response from API_ENDPOINT/challenges? Because thats not possible for us to know. You'd have to talk to the provider of that endpoint.

Comment: The challenge should have 2 possibilities in the response from API_ENDPOINT/challenges? When it fails **url** will be **null**, when it succeeds **url** should return with a **link "/xxxxxxxx"**.

Answer (score 1):

You need parse JSON from string to hash

```rb
json_response = HTTParty.put("#{API_ENDPOINT}/challenges", headers: { 'X-Challenge-Id' => challenge_id })

response = JSON.parse(json_response.body, symbolize_names: true)
```

After that you can process response

```rb
if response[:error]
  puts "Error: #{response[:error]}"
elsif response[:result]
  attempts = response[:result][:attempts]
  url = response[:result][:url]

  if attempts.zero?
    puts "Challenge failed. Attempts: #{attempts}"
  elsif url.nil?
    puts "Challenge succeeded but no URL available. Attempts: #{attempts}"
  else
    puts "Challenge succeeded. Attempts: #{attempts}"
    puts "URL with keyword: #{API_ENDPOINT}#{url}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. However, it still comes back with the same result. This part of the code is in a loop, on the 2nd loop it always comes back with "Response: {"result":{"attempts":1,"url":null}}
Challenge succeeded but no URL available. Attempts: 1" and then stopped.

Comment: It is not this code but your API response issue